# Cardinality of the union of infinite and countable sets

Tags: set-theory

This seems evident, but I cannot come up with a reasonable proof for:

**Question:**
show that if $X$ is an infinite set and $Y$ is a countable set,
then $|X \cup Y|=|X|$

Comment: Do you mean $|X \cup Y| = |X|$?

Comment: And the question is related to the axiom of choice how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**An Idea**: Suppose first that $X$ and $Y$ are both countable, say $X = \{x_1, x_2, ...\}$ and $Y= \{y_1, y_2, ...\}$. Then the function $\phi : Y  \to  X \cup Y$ defined by 
$$\phi(y_i) = \begin{cases} x_{i/2} & i \text{ even} \\
y_{(i+1)/2} & i \text{ odd}
\end{cases}$$
is a bijection, and therefore $|X \cup Y| = |Y|$. More generally, if $Y$ is infinite, there is a countable subset $\tilde{Y} \subset Y$. From what we just showed, you know that there is a bijection $\varphi : X \cup \tilde{Y} \to \tilde{Y}$. Extend this to a bijection $\Phi : X \cup Y \to Y$ by 
$$
\Phi(z) = \begin{cases}
\varphi(z) & z \in X \cup \tilde{Y}\\
z & z \in Y \setminus (X \cup \tilde{Y})
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Of course, I've interchanged your $X$ and $Y$ so that $X$ is assumed countable and $Y$ is assumed infinite.

Comment: phi is only injective if X is infinite I think

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** First show that every infinite set $X$ can be written as the disjoint union of $X_0$ and $X_1$ with $X_0$ being countably infinite. Next show that the union of two countable sets is countable.